# Moving up an UIView when UIWebView's keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiwebview

I am trying to move an UIView when user touch a textfield in a webview , because keyboard will cover the webview and users will not able to enter text , my codes works very fine ! on iOS 7 !!! but iOS 8 the view moves up but when user select another textfield (in webview) the UIView moves down to the initial position !!! . here is my code :

```
/* _contactForm = UIWebView
    _contactView = UIView */



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];   

}


- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif {


      [[[_contactForm subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:YES];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {


    [UIView animateWithDuration:.20
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^
                        {

                         [_contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 37 , _contentView.frame.size.width, _contentView.frame.size.height)];


                        } completion:nil];

    }

}




- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notif{

    [[[_contactForm subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.20
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^
     {

         [_contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 176 , _contentView.frame.size.width, _contentView.frame.size.height)];

     }completion:nil];


    }

}
```

I also tried `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` , but no success !

WebView loads an HTML file from bundle , this is textfield's codes :

```
<form action="http://someurl.net/mail/mail.cshtml" method="post"  onsubmit="return validate();">

    <input class="textInput" type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME"/>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input class="textInput" type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL"/>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input class="textInput" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="PHONE"/>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <textarea name="msg" cols="19" rows="3" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SEND"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Can you give me URl.

Comment: can you please try to set break point on both hide and show methods. I'd like to know if both gets called when user taps from one field to the other.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 its better to use `keyboardFrameDidChange` rather than `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`

Add a listener :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardFrameDidChange:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

Implement the selector :

```
-(void)keyboardFrameDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification{

NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];

CGRect kKeyBoardFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f delay:0 options:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue] animations:^{

   // Do your animation
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [yourView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
}
```

Comment: @Mc.Lover Are you using Autolayout? Is your view pinned to bottom?

Comment: Yes , it goes up ! but by selecting another textfield on the webView it goes back where it was ! my webview is contact form has different textfield

Comment: Just a suggestion. If auto layout is on, then you should change the view's position by adjusting its constraints, not setting frames.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug the specific issue with your views since I don't know how your constraints are set up. You really shouldn't be issuing a setFrame call, especially with fixed numbers for the height and other values!

It's already been pointed out by Sreejith that you can get the keyboard size this way:

`CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notif userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;`

If you don't want to change the constraints directly (don't forget you can IBOutlet them and set the constant) you can try altering the edge insets with something like this:

`self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, self.view.height - keyboardSize.origin.y, 0);`

The animation time should also be driven off they keyboard info:

`NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];`

Linking to a demo project would help a lot in debugging if these suggestions do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with setting the webView's autoresizingMask

```
_webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```